# Crashlytics NDK not respone C++ crash

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm working with NDK Crashlytics in Android. I have used crashlytics NDK system for catch any crash. When I push symbols in crashlytics NDK, I success. But sometime, crashlytics NDK system doesn't work. Some version release can not get any bug C++ (crashlytics java still work). Anybody know why it's happened? Thanks!

More infomation: crashlytics-ndk:2.0.4 minSdkVersion 14 targetSdkVersion 25